# Сортировка списка по рядом стоящим числам

Tags: python

```py
a = [0, 0, 1, 2, 2, 0, 0]
```

Нужно отсортировать и получить

```py
a = [0, 1, 2, 0]
```

Заранее спасибо!

Comment: А это точно сортировка? Больше похоже на удаление рядом стоящих дубликатов.

Comment: Да, не могли бы вы пожалуйста помочь?

Comment: по какому принципу нужно получить то, что нужно получить?

Comment: Нужно удалить все стоящие рядом дубликаты.

Comment: Ну это же учебное задание, есть много способов его решить, зачем вы себя этого удовольствия лишаете?

Comment: `itertools.groupby`.

Answer (score 2):

Наверняка есть более изящные решения, но это первое что пришло в голову

```
data = [0, 0, 1, 2, 2, 2, 0, 0, 1, 3, 3, 3, 3, 0]
new_data = []

last_number = None

for x in data:
    if x != last_number:
        new_data.append(x)
        last_number = x

print(new_data)
```